# Why does this redstone circuit burn out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm testing a circuit with restone but came across a very odd behavior, so I isolated a part of circuit composed of a block with the NOT gate which has a lever attached to it. When I activate the lever, the torch of the NOT gate always burns out.

Why is that?

PS: If you didn't understand just look at [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j48S-g1oTf4&list=UUMPdx9mCjs6rzrxTHan4T3A&index=6&feature=plcp) and look at the beginning of the tutorial (which is in the middle of the video).

Here's a picture:

[image: what the heck!]

Comment: Screenshot of what you have built? Maybe there is an error in your layout. A redstone wire in the wrong place or such.

Comment: Can you post a diagram of your circuit? It would aid debugging immensely!

Comment: @dbemerlin, screenshot posted

Comment: @fredley, I posted a picture, and it is basically all there. I don't even know how to make a correct diagram.

Comment: Your torch isn't supposed to be placed at the opposite of the lever ? (On the opposite side of the wood block)

Comment: @Depado, Even trying this is does burn out

Comment: I don't get it. Your torch never lights ? Did you try with a push button or another activating device ?

Comment: @Depado, when I place it it is on, but then the first time I activate the level (turn off the energy) the torch burns out.

Comment: You may have stumbled upon one of [these bugs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXCzd6M3L8A): "Sometimes, torches can burn out, and even replacing them will not repair the damage"

Comment: So when you flip the switch, the torch stops glowing, and when you reset the switch it starts again. Is that the result you're currently getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fredley suggested, I crossed upon a well know bug. Creating a new world (or probably just change the position of the blocks) will solve the problem.